# How to compare two columns in the same table, and get a distinct one

Tags: mysql

I have a table let's call it a 'options' and some columns in it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `options` (`key` VARCHAR(255), `value` VARCHAR(255), `user` VARCHAR(255));
```

A little data with NULL `user` field for exmaple:

```
INSERT INTO `options` (`key`, `value`) VALUES ('port', '8080'), ('length', '3000'), ('country', 'USA');
```

And a one row with a `user` field named 'John':

```
 INSERT INTO `options` (`key`, `value`, `user`) VALUES ('port', '5000', 'John');
```

First couple of rows have **'User'** column set **NULL**. Other rows in **'User'** column could have names like **'John'** (for example, lets take only one). Think about the **'User'** columns with **NULL** values as a default set of options that I always get out from the database, but some Users like John have individual options and I need to get his option(s) prior to default ones. Here is an image of table:

I need a query to get Johns options **'key', 'value'** parameters where **'User'** is **NULL**, but if some **'User'** like **'John'** has something different from default options (if the 'key' match, **'port'** in this case) I need it to show only John's port, and the others are with 'User' = null, without duplicates, so I need the answer like this:

> key | value | user
>   port | 5000 |John
>   length | 3000 | NULL
>   country | USA | NULL

While the database consists of this:

> key | value | user
>   port | 8080 |NULL
>   length | 3000 | NULL
>   country | USA | NULL
>   port | 5000 | John

I tried a lot of queries but none of them gave me the positive result. Tried something with self join, right join, left join, disctinct columns, with **IFNULL()** function, but everything was wrong. I searched a lot , but can't find an answer to this, so I am humbly ask for help or advice here.

Comment: What are on the images ? I can't see them

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) then you understand we don't like image data.

Comment: Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8398549) too

Comment: I'll edit the post in 15 mins, thanks for your guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first fetch the default key,values pairs, excluding the ones that have a value for the corresponindg user and then use `UNION` and fetch the key,values pairs for the user.

A query using `NOT IN` and a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `options` WHERE `user` IS NULL 
AND `key` NOT IN 
(SELECT `key` FROM `options` WHERE `user`='John')
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `options` WHERE `user`='John'
```

The same query using `JOIN`

```
SELECT o.* FROM `options` o 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT `key` FROM `options` WHERE `user`='John') o2
ON o.key=o2.key WHERE o2.key IS NULL AND o.user IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `options` WHERE `user`='John'
```

Comment: Happy I could help you.I added an example with `JOIN` which may be better performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CASE` clause to apply simple logic to a query. For example:

```
select
  key,
  case when user is not null then user else value end as value
from t
```